# How to specify content in a WCS GetCapabilities request

Tags: wcs, request, getcapabilities

I have the following GetCapabilities request to a GeoServer WCS service:

http://fast.openearth.eu/geoserver/Netherlands_Study_Site_Paulina/wcs?service=WCS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities&

Very neatly it returns me an XML response with a lot of nice information. 
It also returns information, on different contents, i.e. different GeoTIFFs that are located within the folder "Netherlands_Study_Site_Paulina".

However, I am specifically interested in 1 of the GeoTIFFs. For example, there is one with the title: DTM.

Question:
Is there a way to specify which content I want in the GetCapabilities request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify which content I want in the GetCapabilities request?

**No**

The purpose of the GetCapabilities request is to find out what the service can offer, that is the identifiers, the formats, the operations, the supported coordinate reference systems, the languages supported...

Note (as it's discussed in comments), if you want to request a WCS 2.x + service you should use the AcceptVersions parameter, and not the version parameter, like:

http://fast.openearth.eu/geoserver/Netherlands_Study_Site_Paulina/wcs?service=WCS&AcceptVersions=2.0.1,2.0.0,1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities&

Once you have found a coverage identifier that you are interested in the next logical step is to do a DescribeCoverage request.  This provides you with all available metadata about the coverage, but doesn't give you the coverage data itself.

For example:

http://fast.openearth.eu/geoserver/Netherlands_Study_Site_Paulina/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&CoverageId=Netherlands_Study_Site_Paulina__DTM&

Comment: oops, yes, AcceptVersions for version negotiation (now corrected), AcceptLanguages is for language negotiation

Answer (score 0):

While typing the question I had an epiphany and found the answer.

The error in my question is that I want to do a *GetCapabilities* request and specify the content, i.e. identifier/coverage.

It is **not** needed to specify any other keywords in the *GetCapabilities* request. 
If I want to do a request of a specific layer/content/identifier/coverage (many different terms), a *GetCoverage* request is needed.

With wcs version 1.1.0 a *GetCoverage* request can used. With the key word IDENTIFIER, I can specify the content from which I want coverage. 
Furthermore, the following keywords are mandatory for a wcs version 1.1.0 *GetCoverage* request: VERSION, REQUEST, IDENTIFIER,BOUNDINGBOX, FORMAT.

But I am just touching the tip of the iceberg, for a fully detailed explenation, see: http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html

Answer:
No there isn't because *GetCapabilities* requests don't need any other keywords. If you want to specify the content of the WCS request, use for example, the *GetCoverage* request.

Comment: Second step is to do DescribeCoverage, for example http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeCoverage&CoverageID=nurc__Img_Sample. If you just start studying WCS I recommend to learn version 2.0 and forget the older ones.

Comment: really? Just focus on 2.0? The geoserver I am using implements WCS 1.0 and 1.1.1

Comment: The version 2.0 of the standard is much better than the old ones IMHO. Pity if you can't use it. As far as I know the INSPIRE download services will be based on version 2.x if WCS will be accepted as an alternative. New GeoServer versions support it out of the box.

Comment: Whilst the technical guidance for providing an INSPIRE compliant download service for coverage data using WCS is based on WCS 2.x, strictly speaking INSPIRE doesn't mandate this version.  If a data provider wants to use WCS < 2.0 they will need to be able to demonstrate that their service is compliant to the regulation, for example that it can handle language negotiation.  WCS 2.x gets this ability through OWS Common 2.0, earlier versions of WCS don't have any inbuilt language capability...